# Consider the covering map $p: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}^2-0 $ given by $p(x,t) = (t\cos(2\pi x), t\sin(2\pi x))$ add...

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

[Consider the covering map $p: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}^2-0 $ given by $p(x,t) = (t\cos(2\pi x), t\sin(2\pi x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2359651/337659)

Find liftings of the paths

- $f(t) = (2-s,0),$
- $g(t) = ((1+s)\cos(2 \pi s), (1+s)\sin(2 \pi s))$,
- $h(t) = f*g$.

By definition we must find functions $f_1$, $g_1$, $h_1 : X \to  \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $p \circ f_1 = f$, $p \circ g_1 = g$ and $p \circ h_1 = h$. But I don't know how to do that.

and, what about

> **$p^{-1}(1\times 0)$ for $1\times 0\in \mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ and $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}, 1\times 0)$?**

Any help?

Comment: Write a path $\hat{f}:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+$ as $\hat{f}(t)=(\hat{f}_1(t),\hat{f}_2(t))$. Now apply the map $p$, see what you get and work out what the forms of $\hat{f}_1,\hat{f}_2$ must be like if $p\circ\hat{f}=f$, $g$ or$ h$.

Comment: $p^{-1}(1\times 0)=\{(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+\mid p(x,t)=(tcos(2\pi x),tsin(2\pi x)=(1,0)\}$.

Comment: $(\mathbb{R}^2-(0,0))\simeq S^1$ by a homotopy fixing $(1,0)$.